# How to draw coordinates for HTML 5 map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, html5-canvas

I have an outline of Asia as shown below:

[image: http://grab.by/m0Cq]

I want the countries to fill with red when hovered over, such as this:

[image: http://grab.by/m0CI]

The cut-outs exactly fit the map. I've been pretty confused with the information I've found so far on the internet as to how to do this. Some people say HTML 5 maps, others say jQuery, others say SVG... I just want a definitive method of how to accomplish this so I can at least attempt this project. Also, I've found it hard to find good tutorials online, so if a step-by-step method could be told, that would be great (I can find tutorials for each step, just need to know what I should be doing).

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://jvectormap.com/) is what you are searching for.

Comment: You can do it using javascrip library raphaeljs: http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html which is using svg. You have to first convert your map to scalable vector using e.g gimp

Comment: @roasted I can do that with illustrator/photoshop too, right? And what do I do once I get that?

Comment: Then you have svg code with path on which you can apply javascript function/event or css. But raphaeljs is not so easy to use, i suggest you to look at @Eich's link, seems easier.

Comment: At which point does it automatically find the paths? @roasted

Answer (score 2):

SVG allows you to assign CSS style classes to individual shapes. One possible CSS class is the :hover pseudoclass. This allows you to change the styling when the user moves the mouse on the shape.

An example how to do this, can be found here:
http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/